# Rails, Failed assertion, no message given

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to write a unit test for models I keep getting the same error and cant seem to fix it.

This is my test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
test "product attirbutes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
end

  test "product price must be positive" do
    product = Product.new(title:       "My Book Title",
                          description: "yyy",
                          image_url:   "zzz.jpg")

    product.price = -1
        # line number 19 below
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
      product.errors[:price]

    product.price = 0
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"], 
      product.errors[:price]

    product.price = 1
    assert product.valid?
  end

end
```

When I run > rake test

I get the following error:

```
 1) Failure:
ProductTest#test_product_price_must_be_positive
/test/models/product_test.rb:19]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

Here is my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
validates :price, numericality: {greater_then_or_equal_to: 0.01}
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a url for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
}
end
```

I have no idea what is going on here please help!

Comment: So, what's on line 19?

Answer (score 2):

As per the MiniTest::Assertions [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#assert-method), any method derived from 'assert' will raise the exception message "Failed assertion, no message given" on a fail unless you supply the optional 'msg' paramater

---

A few things:

1. you are testing Active Record validations, these are tried and tested, production ready features of a library so testing it is not necessary. To become more familiar with Active Record validations just go the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and then play around with your models in the rails console
2. Active record validations are only performed when attempt to 'create' or 'save'
   a model. For example:

   ```
   my_user = User.create(name: nil, email: nil) # try save to DB - fails silently
   my_user.valid? # => false
   my_user.errors.messages # => {name:["can't be blank"], email:["can't be blank"]}
   ```

---

Maybe explore some futher learning on the topic, the Ryan Bate's screencasts are great and free for the most part. Hope this helps

Note: I hoped to attach some more links/refrences however I do not have the Stackoverflow points to do

Answer (score 1):

your model is wrong.

(line 3)　　　　　　　　　　
                                                                                                       　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　  　　　       ↓

wrong)     validates :price, numericality: {greater_then_or_equal_to: 0.01}

correct)   validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}

not "then" but "than".